# Can a US Citizen living in Canada, get a license to carry firearms while visiting the US?

Tags: usa, firearms, citizen

I live in Canada, do not have a firearms license in Canada as I'm a USA citizen and a "Permanent Resident" of Canada.
Is there a way to legally own and purchase a weapon in the US, if I have a residence to store it at while I'm in Canada?

Comment: To clarify, a residence *in the US* to store it at, while you're in Canada?

Comment: The answer would depend, I think, both upon whatever federal requirements might exist, and the requirements of the state in which the applicant applies for a license. I can imagine that the requirements in New York, for example, probably differ from those of Texas.

Comment: Do you have a US driver's license, and is it from the state you are visiting?

Comment: You want to store it in Canada but do not have a firearms license in Canada? Sounds illegal to me.

Comment: Putting on hold until clarified about where she's storing the firearm

Comment: The weapon would be stored in the US, not in Canada, while I am in Canada. When I travel to the States, I would retrieve it for the duration of travel.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the license to carry (aka, CCW), yes, probably.  As with all things firearm, the laws vary by state.  Some states will issue licenses to out of state residents.  In fact some states will let you do it by mail.  Best would be to get a license in the state that you plan to spend time in, this way if there is a problem it can be quickly validated.  An alternative is to get a license in a state that has a reciprocity agreement with the state(s) that you will be spending time in. (You can see what states recognize whose licenses at a site like [usacarry.com](https://www.usacarry.com/concealed_carry_permit_reciprocity_maps.html)).  Also note that some states do not require licenses for concealed carry.  And in other states, its very difficult to get a license at all, even for residents.

Purchasing a handgun may be more difficult. I consulted a friend of mine who's a firearms trainer on what's required for a handgun purchase.  He said their store would require a driver's license or state ID from his state, or proof that you owned residential property in the state (along with, obviously, an instant background check).  And he believes the rules are similar in most other states. So the question may be, do you still have a US driver's license?  If not, you may need to renew it.

Ultimately, given your situation, since the laws vary so much from state to state, it will be best for you to visit a gun store the next time you are in the US and verify from them their state's requirements.  They can probably also provide info on their state's CCW license requirements.  Some may have some modest training requirements for licenses (usually a few hours attending classroom training).

Comment: A permanent resident of Canada will not normally have a US driver's license.  She ought to have a US passport, though; will that do?  Why would a driver's license be necessary?

Comment: @phoog Note I said License/ID (i.e., license *or* ID, so any will do).  But dealers may not want or be able to sell handguns to people who cannot show in-state residence (or sometimes residence in a neighboring state).

Comment: Well, I assumed that you meant "license or DMV-issued non-driver ID," but it makes more sense now that I know the assumption was incorrect.  But if a dealer were concerned about in-state residence, would a US passport plus evidence showing (I presume from "residence to store it at") an in-state vacation home or similar be enough despite the Canadian permanent residence (and presumably Canadian driver's license)?

Comment: @phoog  One would think the passport would be sufficient, so long as it showed a suitable US address. (answer updated & clarified)

Comment: US passports do not show the bearer's address, unless the bearer follows the instruction to enter the address in pencil in the appropriate place.  In other words, the address is only for reference; the document does not serve as official proof of address.

Comment: @phoog My passport does show a state, which may be sufficient.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99990/discussion-between-phoog-and-grandmasterb).

Comment: For a US residence, I have family that live in different states in the US which I spend a lot of time at. The idea being that while I am in the US, I would be legally able to carry, and the weapon would be stored in the US, when I travel back to Canada. The only reason for the firearm in the first place is that I frequently travel in the states, by myself. As a single female on the road, it's peace of mind.

Comment: @Claudia you may want to pay special attention to states that have reciprocity with the states you plan to visit using that link I posted.  Check for each state you will be visiting to see if a license from one of them would work best.  Depending where you are it may range from very easy to go from state to state, to completely illegal (i.e., you're probably out of luck if one of the states is New Jersey, even as a resident).  You don't have to justify it to me... I have a CCW and rarely travel without.  Luckily all the states I typically visit have reciprocity with mine.

Comment: @Claudia I'm going to check with a friend of mine who's a trainer, and see what he says about the purchase requirements.  That may be a couple days.

Comment: @Claudia Answer updated based on info from my friend.